# Why does my matlab program use so much memory?

Tags: matlab, memory

I am writing a matlab program, which reads about 500 files. Each file has 20,000 lines, with 1 number on each line. The program tries to build a matrix of 20,000 * 500 with these numbers.
The numbers are stored as Double, so 8 bytes per number. So I would expect this to take 20,000 * 500 * 8 bytes, which is approximately 1E8, i.e. 100MB. And yet this program exhausts my 16GB memory. As the program runs, I see the memory use steadily going up, GB by GB. I am using Matlab R2015b on Ubuntu 14.04.

What's happening? Many thanks for your attention.

Here is the full code

```
clear all;
% number of rna bits in the file
filesize = 20532

maxFiles = 480;
rnaCounts = NaN(filesize,maxFiles);

myFolder = '~/_STATS/data3/RNASeqV2/UNC__IlluminaHiSeq_RNASeqV2/Level_3';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*genes.normalized_results');

theFiles = dir(filePattern);

rnaCounts = NaN(filesize,length(theFiles));


for k = 1 : length(theFiles) 
    mrnaFilename = strtrim(theFiles(k).name);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading mrnaFile %d %s  \n', k, mrnaFilename);

    % read rna file
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, mrnaFilename);
    rnafid = fopen(fullFileName);

    if rnafid < 0 
       fprintf('====ERROR OPENING RNA FILE =====================');
    end
    rnaline = fgets(rnafid);

    lc = 1;  % line counter
    while ischar(rnaline) && feof(rnafid) ~= 1
       rnaline = fgets(rnafid);
       rnaSplit = strsplit(rnaline);

       % write to the matrix
       rnaCounts(lc,k) = str2num(rnaSplit{2});

       lc = lc + 1;
    end
    fclose(rnafid);

end
```

Comment: One thing to try is delete the first instance of `rnaCounts`; it is unused and very big, though that shouldn't be what is blowing the memory up.

Comment: Also, try `str2double` rather than `str2num`. That is not exactly was `str2num` is for. `help str2num` and `help str2double`

Comment: Are you sure the memory is being held by Matlab and its not just the filesystem cache? e.g. If you kill Matlab, does all the memory immediately clear?

Comment: @old_Mortality: you could store the current data in a `*.mat` file and reload it for each iteration. Inbetween each iteration use `clear all` to *hopefully* free some memory. Not very elegant but it might work

Comment: Can you add one sample line of the data you are reading? From the code I assume that you have one header line which you ignore - is this correct? My suggestion would be to use a high-level I/O function instead of using low-level functions and manually doing conversions.

Comment: I can't explain the issue, in fact I had the same problem with my code once (until a complete rewrite), but maybe this info helps:
http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/big-data-matlab.html

Comment: Thank you very much for all the suggestions. The problem was solved by @drhagen's idea to replace strnum() by strdouble(). So I have learned now that strnum() operates on a matrix, while strdouble() should be used for a single string. Quite an unexpected side-effect of strnum()!

Comment: Try this to track the issue: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/profiling-matlab-memory-usage if you have issues understanding the output, generate a report (html) and upload it somewhere

Comment: @RobertStettler. Yes, that would probably work, but I needed to know what causes this, or I may run into this problem at any corner.

Comment: @hbaderts. Here is a sample line:"A2LD1|87769 135.5735".How would I use high-level I/O ?

Comment: @Daniel, Thank you, I will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

As verified by the OP, the `str2num` function in the Linux version of Matlab 2015b has a memory leak. This function is not very useful anyway as it is designed to parse strings representing entire matrices (`1 2; 3 4`) rather than the typical use case of parsing a single number (`1.234`). Use `str2double` when doing simple number parsing; it is faster even when `str2num` isn't broken.

It is likely that using a different version of Matlab would also work around the problem, because in my experience, these kinds of memory bugs don't usually persist from one version to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Often, high-level I/O functions, such as [`dlmread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) or [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) are useful to read such text formats. Use `dlmread` if you have only *numeric* data,
and `textscan` for more complex formats.

The sample data you provided is:

> `A2LD1|87769  135.5735`

As you only need the number in the second column and discard the identifier in the first column, all you have is numeric data, and you can use `dlmread`.

```
data = dlmread(fullFileName, '\t', 1, 1);
```

The `\t` is to specify that the delimiter (column separator) is a Tab. The two `1`s are to specify a row offset and a column offset, i.e. ignore the first row (the header) and the first column (id) of the file.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.